# Is it ever necessary to instantiate new HttpRequest objects in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view that authenticates a user. If the user is authenticated, the program should call another view with the request and user as parameters.

```
    def home(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                return index(request, user)
            else:
                 context = {'error_message': "That username and password don't exist in our system."}
                 return render(request, 'list/home.html', context)
```

So, when index gets called, the request is the same instance as the request send to the home view, right? My concern is that the request is still a POST request when it should be a GET request.

Is this a misconception? Should I create a new request object and send it to index?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect%22redirect%22) method

```
if user is not None:
    return redirect(reverse('index'))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the excellent ["What technical details should a programmer of a web application consider before making the site public?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before/46760#46760),

> Redirect after a POST if that POST was successful, to prevent a refresh from submitting again.

So you're right, you'll want to redirect to make sure that the previous form isn't submitted. but further from that, you shouldn't think about views as being directly linkable and instead get into the mindset that a view is what you get to from making a request. So as afilardo suggests, you should redirect.

```
return redirect('index')
```